# Find the outer measure of set of rationals in [-1,1]

Tags: measure-theory

What is the outer measure of the set of rationals in [-1,1]?
I've read that it is infinity? I believe that it is countable. Then why it is infinity?

Comment: The outer measure of any subset of $[-1,1]$ cannot be greater than the total measure of the space, which is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Every, countable set is (Borel- and Lebesgue-) measurable, so the outer measure coincides with the measure. And every countable set has Lebesgue measure zero.